# Jquery Template not aligning

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, jquery-templates

I have a one html  `table` .

```
<table id="blogPostContainer">
</table>
```

I was append some values in this table using `signalR` and `tmpl` .

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                booking.server.getAllDates().done(function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        DateTempl = DateTempl.concat(data[i].Dates);
                    }
                    var blogPosts = { Date: [DateTempl] }
                    $("#blogPostTemplate").tmpl(blogPosts).appendTo("#blogPostContainer");

                });
            });
```

And I am align `table tr td` formatting using by jquery taemplate

```
<script id="blogPostTemplate" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl"> 

        <tr>
            <td>
            Date
            </td>
             {{each Date}} <td> ${$value} </td> {{/each}}
        </tr>


    </script>
```

The  first `tr` and `td` tag are working . But inside of the each loop `td` tag not working

Please see my result below
[image]

First `Td` working but second `td` not working . I want my each date's want to inside of `td` tag. any one help me

Comment: What is `DateTempl`? By the way if `DateTemplv` is an array you are wrapping it in an array with `var blogPosts = { Date: [DateTempl] }`. So it should be `var blogPosts = { Date: DateTempl }`...

Comment: The  DateTempl is declared globally in top side . that nit a problem buddy

Comment: Have you had a look at the source of the page?

Comment: @nemesv Your comment is working good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altough you haven't posted your `DateTempl` declaration but it seems it's an array. And with the `[DateTempl]` call you wrap it into another array in the following statement

```
var blogPosts = { Date: [DateTempl] };
```

So in the query template the `${$value}` will display your whole array in one table cell.

You just need to remove the `[]` and it should work fine:

```
var blogPosts = { Date: DateTempl };
```